# Error 1062 duplicate entry '0' for key 'primary'

Tags: mysql

can't add primary key for ID table and how to fix it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj4I0.png

Comment: is it an empty table ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here. Please don't use images for information that is easily communicated in text. Images are not friendly to search or copy & paste or visually impaired people. This is covered in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should read that page and others in the help center before posting.

Answer (score 3):

It seems as though you have multiple rows in the table that have `id = 0`.

In order to add the primary key to the table you'll need to either delete those duplicate rows or update their `id` fields to be a unique value.